# Programmatically writing to a notebook in TraditionalForm

Tags: notebooks

I'm trying to get a Cell to appear in TraditionalForm when using `NotebookWrite`. Here is the closest I can get:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Hello", "Section"]];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@TraditionalForm@"HI", "Text"]];
```

I get the following:

[image: nb output]

What do I need to do to get "HI" to appear in TraditionalForm?

**Edit:**

Here's a better example:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Sin[x]^2]], "Output"]];
```

gives

[image]

whereas I'd like the output to look like

[image]

Is there a specific option I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ToBoxes` takes a second argument where you can specify the form that you desire. In your case, use `TraditionalForm`:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Sin[x]^2, TraditionalForm]], "Text"]];
```

[image]

Note that the styling will also depend on how the cell style treats `TraditionalForm` text. For instance, change the cell style from `"Text"` to `"Output"` in the above and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what `TraditionalForm` has to look like, but maybe setting the type to "Output" does what you want:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Hello", "Section"]];
NotebookWrite[nb, 
Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@TraditionalForm@"HI", "Output"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better but not quite what I'm after. I'd prefer it to look like `TraditionalForm["HI"]` instead of `"HI"`.

Comment: @RiemannZeta you should try to be clearer as to what you want that is not satisfied by tis answer. I am not understanding. Maybe posting images even if necessary. Or the cell expression of a cell that shows like you intend

Comment: @Rojo see my edit above. Thanks.