# NotebookWrite Cell with Grid

Tags: notebooks

I'd like to `NotebookWrite` a `Cell` in `StandardForm` with a `Grid` to a new document. What I'd like to copy is

```
toCopy = TraditionalForm@Grid[{{a^2, b^2, c^2}, {d^2, e^2, f^2}}]
```

If I now use the following code

```
NotebookWrite[
 CreateDocument[]
 , toCopy]
```

I get a red rectangle in the new Notebookbook. I've tried to change all letters a to f to "a" ... "f", but nothing changed.

I am somewhat puzzled... What I missing here?
Thanks for all help, as always!

Edit: With the answer of Alexey, it works good to copy the `Grid` to the new Notebook. But the TraditionalForm is lost: I get InputForm. Even using

```
NotebookWrite[
 CreateDocument[],
  ToBoxes[toCopy, TraditionalForm]]
```

doesn't seem to work. Any more help, as always, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You should pass boxes as the second argument to `NotebookWrite`:

```
toCopy = Grid[{{a^2, b^2}, {c^2, d^2}}];
NotebookWrite[CreateDocument[], ToBoxes@toCopy]
```

Answering your second question, it is sufficient to wrap the expression by `TraditionalForm` to get it in `TraditionalForm`:

```
NotebookWrite[CreateDocument[], ToBoxes@TraditionalForm@toCopy]
```

But it still gives you an `"Input"` `Cell`. If you wish to generate an `"Output"` `Cell`, you should specify it explicitly:

```
NotebookWrite[CreateDocument[], 
 Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@TraditionalForm@toCopy, "Output"]]
```

P.S. Also, see relevant discussion in this thread: "[Programmatically writing to a notebook in TraditionalForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18037/280)."

Comment: Thanks, this works good for the copying, but changes back to InputForm (I think), and not TraditionalForm. I appreciate any help for this problem!

Comment: @Gabriel Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution analysing the output of *Mathematica* with `"Show Expression"`.
To display the contents of a `Cell` in `TraditionalForm`, one has to use a
`FormBox[ ..., TraditionalForm]` around the boxes given to `Cell` (for example, using `ToBoxes`,
as follows:

```
NotebookWrite[ 
    CreateDocument[],
    Cell[ FormBox[ ToBoxes @ Grid[{{a^2, b^2}, {c^2, d^2}}], TraditionalForm] ]
             ]
```

Thanks for informing if I misunderstood somewhere along the lines...
Hope this helps to other *Mathematica* users.

Comment: I noticed that if one of the variable is instead a string, the quotation signs becomes visible in the resulting notebook.