# Document Creation: inserting a grid

Tags: document-creation

This question is strongly related to:

[NotebookWrite Cell with Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35654/notebookwrite-cell-with-grid/35659#35659)

Let’s create sample chart

```
mydata = {{"Noise Density \n(\[Mu]g/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Hz\), \
\(0.5\)]\))", "Mean", "StDev", "Min", "Q1", "Median", "Q3", 
"Max"}, {"X ", 5., 4., 21., 26., 29., 33., 35.}, {"Y ", 25., 5., 
18., 20., 25., 29., 34.}, {"Z ", 39., 4., 30., 38., 39., 40., 
47.}};


myChart = 
  Grid[mydata
, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"
, FontTracking -> "SemiCondensed", FontWeight -> “Thin”, FontSize -> 10}
, Frame -> True
, Dividers -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
, Spacings -> {2, 1}
, Alignment -> {{Center, Left}, Right}
, Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}}]
```

The chart renders OK on evaluation:

[image: sample chart]

However, when I try to write the chart to a new document:

```
CreateDocument[ ExpressionCell@myChart]
```

It inserts it as follows:

[image: Probelmatic chart]

**What is the correct method of writing a grid to a document?**

Comment: Does this work for what you need: `CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[myChart, ShowStringCharacters -> False]]`?

Comment: Great… if you post it as an answer that would be great…

Comment: @kguler: I can’t seem to do: SetOptions[ExpressionCell, ShowStringCharacters -> False]; and have it propagate through out my document creations… any ideas?

Comment: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowStringCharacters -> False]` works?

Comment: Yes. That seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[myChart, ShowStringCharacters -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I feel like the amount of styling options with unintuitive default behaviour is "too ... high" :)

Comment: @Kuba, agree .. :)

Comment: :-) Not to mention that ShowStringCharacters does not appear in the Documentation for ExpressionCell

Answer (score 1):

Use the expression cell style, `"Print"`:-

```
CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[myChart, "Print"]]
```

Comment: "Output" will work too but with both there is a difference in `CellMargins` in comparision to simple `ExpressionCell`.